# jQuery datepicker more than one input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery 2.1.0 and am trying to use a datepicker for more than one input. I can get it to work on the first input but how do I get it to work for the second? Any Suggestions?

http://jsfiddle.net/j02p2sed/

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
Date:</label>
<input type="text" name="odate" id="datepicker">
Date2:<input type="text" name="purchasedate" id="datepicker" mask="99/99/9999">
```

```
 $(function() {

        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();

      });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just give every datepicker another id...

```
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
Date:</label>
<input type="text" name="odate" id="datepicker">
Date2:<input type="text" name="purchasedate" id="datepicker1" mask="99/99/9999">
```

Jquery:

```
 $(function() {

 $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
 $( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker();
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Every datepicker should have it's own ID.

**HTML code:**

```
Date:</label>
<input type="text" name="odate" id="datepicker1">
Date2:<input type="text" name="purchasedate" id="datepicker2" mask="99/99/9999">
```

**JS code:**

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker();
    $( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker();
  });
```

Here is the working **[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/j02p2sed/1/)**